# How to replace automatically the value of Id with old value of Id after delete a row in SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I have a little problem.

When I delete a row in my dataGrid, the row is deleted successful. But when I insert another record into database, Id will not replace the old Id of the row that I have deleted before.

Id is:

```
Identity Increment = 1
Identity Seed      = 1
```

Comment: This is correct - and it's **as designed**. Once an `IDENTITY` value has been given out, it is **never recycled**. This would make auditing a horrible mess! Once an `IDENTITY` value is used (and a row deleted), it's ***NOT*** recycled - and that's a **good thing!**

Comment: Also see: [stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc, I won't really worry about gaps.